# A function that will represent the total cost

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A farmer wishes to fence in a rectangular field of $10,000$ sq. feet. The north-south fences will cost $\$$1.50 per foot and the east-west  will cost $\$$6 per foot.  If $x$ is the width of the said field, write a function $C(x)$ that will represent the total cost needed to fence in the field.

I'm really having a hard time at analyzing it. Should I represent the north-south and east-west with different variable? But I don't think that's right. I don't know what function to use.

Comment: It's useful to draw a diagram. So you have a rectangle. You can mark the east-west length as $x$. What is the value of the north-south length? Hint: the area of the rectangle is equal to $10~000$.

Comment: is it 10 000/x ?

Comment: Yes. Now you should be able to compute the total cost function.

Comment: C(x)=1.5x + (10 000/x)(6)

Comment: did i get it right?

Comment: Yes, it looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: it must be $C(x)=3x+120000/x$ as there are two pairs of opposite sides.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a second variable, but, as is my preference, you can if you want to.
By doing this, we end of with a system of two equations to solve.

$$C(x) = 2(1.50x + 6.00y)$$
$$xy=10,000$$

Then you can solve for $y$ in the second equation, and just substitute it into the first one.